# Mysql - Phpmaydmin - Not processing all inputs in SQL Window

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I do have a MySQL Server and administration is done via pypMyAdmin. All works fine since "forever" but now I realized that I am having a problem:

Often I do SQL Updates using the "SQL" Link (Run SQL query/queries on server).

If entering a lot of Statements (like this):

```
UPDATE table SET column = 'new value A' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE table SET column = 'new value B' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE table SET column = 'new value C' WHERE id = 3;
....
UPDATE table SET column = 'new value Z' WHERE id = 100;
```

I have encountered that only about 40-50 Statements are done - no error messages, nothing seems broken - just not all 100 or more short SQL Statements are fullfilled ...

Did any of you encounter the same or even better:

What can be done to make sure all lines/SQL Statements are processed?

Comment: It returns any error?

Comment: No Error - All "looks" good ... 50 lines or less are handled ok, above that, lines may be skipped

Answer (score 0):

Not much can be done.  I've encountered the same thing and am comfortable submitting a *few* statements at a time via phpMyAdmin, but for anything more than say 20 simple statments I go to my MySQL host and import a file with all my statements like $>mysql -u me -pmypass mydb < file_with_many_statements.sql

There's clearly a limitation that could depend on a number of factors (native to phpMyAdmin, settings in your phpMyAdmin hosts's php/web server/mysql configs, network issues, etc.)